# Replacing my RAM / New memory sticks

Tags: memory

**I bought some new Memory Sticks and i want to know on which part they go on.** I have a image too. Can someone help me out? This is my Old Mac i used to use and now i bought a Snow leopard installation disc and i want to add new RAM to my old mac. Can someone just show me where the memory goes?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is it:

[image]

I'd go to [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com) for complete instructions on RAM removal and installation.

You will need to remove the old RAM first unless there is an open slot available.

If you haven't already, you should most definitely follow procedures to minimize [ESD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge) to keep from damaging the RAM and other components inside.

Comment: I went on iFixit, gave my specs, added the RAM from the steps, and now im at the OS X Utilities. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Im now installing **Snow leopard** onto it, thanks for the help.